# VSCode + Xdebug + PHP configuration

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, xdebug, vscode-debugger

I'm trying to set up Xdebug with VScode, but whenever I set breakpoints it's just ignoring it.

I installed https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=felixfbecker.php-debug and followed the instructions (Windows), I also used the Xdebug Wizard,  here is my configuration :

**Vscode - launch.json**

```
{
  "name": "Listen for XDebug",
  "type": "php",
  "request": "launch",
  "port": 9000
},
{
  "name": "Launch currently open script",
  "type": "php",
  "request": "launch",
  "program": "${file}",
  "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
  "port": 9000
}
```

**php.ini**

```
zend_extension = D:\wamp\bin\php\php7.1.16\ext\php_xdebug-2.6.1-7.1-vc14.dll

[XDebug]
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_log=D:\wamp\logs\xdebug.log
```

Note: I can't find any logs, I probably didn't set it correclty but I don't know how to make it work either

**php -v**

```
$ php -v
PHP 7.1.16 (cli) (built: Mar 28 2018 21:27:36) ( ZTS MSVC14 (Visual C++ 2015) x8
6 )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
with Xdebug v2.6.1, Copyright (c) 2002-2018, by Derick Rethans
```

Thank you for reading !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe you may need the following in your `php.ini`:

```
xdebug.remote_connect_back=1
```

See the [`xdebug.ini`](https://github.com/wplib/php-docker/blob/master/7.2.6/files/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini) for WPLib Box’s PHP container which definitely works with XDEBUG and VS Code.