# remote debbugging won't stop at breakpoint with Docker, VScode

Tags: php, docker, debugging, visual-studio-code, xdebug

remote debbugging won't stop at breakpoint.

How remote debbugging stop at a breakpoint?

## usage

- Visual Studio Code (with php-debug extension)
- xdebug(version 2.6.0)
- Docker (version 18.09.0-ce-beta1)
- docker-compose (version 1.22.0)

## xdebug config

I can see `with Xdebug v2.6.0` and xdebug config in phpinfo,
so xdebug config is correctly set!

This is xdebug config

```
$ php -i | grep xdebug                                                                                                                        
xdebug                                                                                                                                        
xdebug support => enabled                                                                                                                     
xdebug.auto_trace => Off => Off                                                                                                               
xdebug.cli_color => 0 => 0                                                                                                                    
xdebug.collect_assignments => Off => Off                                                                                                      
xdebug.collect_includes => On => On                                                                                                           
xdebug.collect_params => 0 => 0                                                                                                               
xdebug.collect_return => Off => Off                                                                                                           
xdebug.collect_vars => Off => Off                                                                                                             
xdebug.coverage_enable => On => On                                                                                                            
xdebug.default_enable => On => On                                                                                                             
xdebug.dump.COOKIE => no value => no value                                                                                                    
xdebug.dump.ENV => no value => no value                                                                                                       
xdebug.dump.FILES => no value => no value                                                                                                     
xdebug.dump.GET => no value => no value                                                                                                       
xdebug.dump.POST => no value => no value                                                                                                      
xdebug.dump.REQUEST => no value => no value                                                                                                   
xdebug.dump.SERVER => no value => no value                                                                                                    
xdebug.dump.SESSION => no value => no value                                                                                                   
xdebug.dump_globals => On => On                                                                                                               
xdebug.dump_once => On => On                                                                                                                  
xdebug.dump_undefined => Off => Off                                                                                                           
xdebug.extended_info => On => On                                                                                                              
xdebug.file_link_format => no value => no value                                                                                               
xdebug.filename_format => no value => no value                                                                                                
xdebug.force_display_errors => Off => Off                                                                                                     
xdebug.force_error_reporting => 0 => 0                                                                                                        
xdebug.gc_stats_enable => Off => Off                                                                                                          
xdebug.gc_stats_output_dir => /tmp => /tmp                                                                                                    
xdebug.gc_stats_output_name => gcstats.%p => gcstats.%p                                                                                       
xdebug.halt_level => 0 => 0
xdebug.idekey => vscode => vscode
xdebug.max_nesting_level => 256 => 256  
xdebug.max_stack_frames => -1 => -1    
xdebug.overload_var_dump => 2 => 2
xdebug.profiler_aggregate => Off => Off
xdebug.profiler_append => Off => Off
xdebug.profiler_enable => Off => Off
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger => Off => Off
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger_value => no value => no value
xdebug.profiler_output_dir => /tmp => /tmp
xdebug.profiler_output_name => cachegrind.out.%p => cachegrind.out.%p
xdebug.remote_addr_header => no value => no value
xdebug.remote_autostart => On => On
xdebug.remote_connect_back => Off => Off
xdebug.remote_cookie_expire_time => 3600 => 3600
xdebug.remote_enable => On => On
xdebug.remote_handler => dbgp => dbgp
xdebug.remote_host => host.docker.internal => host.docker.internal
xdebug.remote_log => no value => no value
xdebug.remote_mode => req => req
xdebug.remote_port => 90055555 => 90055555
xdebug.remote_timeout => 200 => 200
xdebug.scream => Off => Off
xdebug.show_error_trace => Off => Off
xdebug.show_exception_trace => Off => Off
xdebug.show_local_vars => Off => Off
xdebug.show_mem_delta => Off => Off
xdebug.trace_enable_trigger => Off => Off
xdebug.trace_enable_trigger_value => no value => no value
xdebug.trace_format => 0 => 0
xdebug.trace_options => 0 => 0
xdebug.trace_output_dir => /tmp => /tmp
xdebug.trace_output_name => trace.%c => trace.%c
xdebug.var_display_max_children => 128 => 128
xdebug.var_display_max_data => 512 => 512
xdebug.var_display_max_depth => 3 => 3
```

## VSCode config

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [

        {
            "name": "stackOverflow",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 9005,
            "pathMappings": {
                "/app": "/home/user/test"
              }
        },
        {
            "name": "Launch currently open script",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "port": 9000
        }
    ]
}
```

## note

- xdebug won't stop at also `xdebug_break()`;
  Does this mean that xdebug and docker host are not connected?
- changing xdebug_remote_host from host.docker.internal to `127.18.0.4` also fails

Comment: I tried answering your question but Yvette Colomb deleted my answer because it was the same answer I gave to an almost identical question. So in interest of actually  helping you rather than just closing your question as a duplicate as she requested here is the link to that prior answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52737017/102699  - Specifically try adding `xdebug.remote_connect_back=1` to your `php.ini`.

Comment: Thank you ! I tried it, but There was no change. Are there any other ideas?

Comment: Hmm.  That usually does the trick.  Maybe you can see how our PHP containers are configured since they all work with XDEBUG and VSCode: https://github.com/wplib/php-docker

Comment: I use official docker container for phalcon.https://github.com/phalcon/dockerfiles/blob/master/php-fpm/7.2-min/Dockerfile. I do not want to change containers...

Comment: My suggestion was not to change containers but to inspect the source for one that is known to work so you can figure out why the one you want to use does not work.

Comment: OK! I'll try it!

Comment: I tried to challenge, but eventually I didn't understood how to do it.Sorry, but please let me know the procedure.