# Visual Studio Code PHP Debug does not stop on breakpoints for Docker project

Tags: php, docker, visual-studio-code, xdebug, vscode-debugger

I cannot get the VS Code extension "Php debug" to stop on any breakpoints.  I am running the php project (that I want to debug) from Docker on my Ubuntu laptop. Any advice greatly appreciated.

My set up:

- PHP version on Docker: 7.1
- XDebug version on Docker: 2.6.1
- PHP Debug version in VS Code (on my laptop): 1.12.6

My VS Code launch.json file is:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Listen for XDebug",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 9000,
            "log": true,
            "pathMappings": {
                "/var/www/html": "/home/chris/my-test-debugging-project"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "Launch currently open script",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "port": 9000
        }
    ]
}
```

my /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini config is:

```
zend_extension=/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
xdebug.remote_host=172.17.0.2
xdebug.remote_log=/var/www/html/xdebug.log
xdebug.remote_connect_back=0
xdebug.remote_port=9000
```

XDebug logfile (from setting xdebug.remote_log in php.ini):

```
    Log opened at 2018-10-14 05:47:16
    I: Connecting to configured address/port: 172.17.0.2:9000.
    W: Creating socket for '172.17.0.2:9000', poll success, but error: Operation now in progress (29).
    E: Could not connect to client. :-(
    Log closed at 2018-10-

14 05:47:16
```

The PHP Debug log output (from setting "log": true in launch.json):

```
<- launchResponse
Response {
seq: 0,
type: 'response',
request_seq: 2,
command: 'launch',
success: true }
```

Comment: lines in the xdebug.ini have changed in xdebug 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting `xdebug.remote_connect_back=1` and let me know if that works.

If it does we should probably close this question as a duplicate of the question [that I previously answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52737017/102699).

Comment: This has been renamed to xdebug.discover_client_host  in xdebug 3

Answer (score 0):

As i know 9000 is the php-fpm port that use by default. So if you use the same port for the `xdebug.remote_port=9000` It will not work. You can check that by nginx conf as an example mine `cat /etc/nginx/conf.d/site.conf` you can check the line `fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;` or run `lsof -n -iTCP:9000 | grep LISTEN` will show if its utilized. I would suggest you to

- change it to something not used ex: 10000
- `xdebug.remote_host` might wrong, login to the container and try to ping the `172.17.0.2` if it is not working your `xdebug.remote_host` is wrong. Find the ip of the host machine replace it with the current `172.17.0.2`

Comment: I checked the ip and it was correct.  I changed the port number but the result was the same unfortunatlely

Answer (score 0):

I run a local linux web server on a VM. And using samba i mapped on a Windows device letter my share.I followed all the suggestions but the breakpoints where not working as supposed. I could only debug adding "stopOnEntry": true" to launch.json, but not on personally added breakpoints, they were all ignored. 
My problem was the path where my app was running, i fixed like this:

```
{
        "name": "Listen for XDebug",
        "type": "php",
        "request": "launch",
        "port": 9900,             
        "log": true,
       "stopOnEntry": false,
        "pathMappings": {
             "/var/www/html/booking" : "z:",

          }
 },

    {
        "name": "Launch currently open script",
        "type": "php",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${file}",
        "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
        "port": 9900
    }
]
```

}

This obiouvsly is my linux path ->  "/var/www/html/booking" 
And this is drive mapped letter ->  "z:"